# Can't restore tensorflow session without saving all over again

Tags: python, tensorflow

Here is the code:

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
import tensorflow as tf


# print(os.getcwd())
# os.chdir(os.getcwd())
# os.chdir("/tmp")


chk_file = "hello.chk"
def save(checkpoint_file=chk_file):
    with tf.Session() as session:
        x = tf.Variable(initial_value=[1, 2, 3], name="x")
        y = tf.Variable(initial_value=[[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0]], name="y")
        session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        print(session.run(tf.global_variables()))
        saver = tf.train.Saver()
        save_path = saver.save(sess=session, save_path=checkpoint_file)
        print(session.run(tf.global_variables()))



def restore(checkpoint_file=chk_file):
    with tf.Session() as session:
        saver = tf.train.Saver()
        saver.restore(sess=session, save_path=checkpoint_file)
        print(session.run(tf.global_variables()[0]))
        print(tf.global_variables()[0])
        # print(session.run(tf.get_variable("x", shape=(3, ))))

def reset():
    tf.reset_default_graph()

path = save()
# print(path)
restore("/home/kaiyin/PycharmProjects/text-classify/hello.chk")
```

A few problems:

- `restore(path)` doesn't work, contrary to what's describe in the documentation of `saver.restore`
- Relative path does not work for `restore`, even if you are already in the right directory
- If you comment out the `path = save()` line, you get an error:

  /home/kaiyin/virtualenvs/tensorflow/bin/python /home/kaiyin/PycharmProjects/text-classify/restore.py
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/kaiyin/PycharmProjects/text-classify/restore.py", line 38, in 
      restore("/home/kaiyin/PycharmProjects/text-classify/hello.chk")
    File "/home/kaiyin/PycharmProjects/text-classify/restore.py", line 27, in restore
      saver = tf.train.Saver()
    File "/home/kaiyin/virtualenvs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1040, in **init**
      self.build()
    File "/home/kaiyin/virtualenvs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1061, in build
      raise ValueError("No variables to save")
  ValueError: No variables to save

  Process finished with exit code 1

I can live with the first two problems, but the third one is a real blocker. Why on earth do I need to save a session **every time** I want to restore it? It's also a bit mysterious how the `save` function could have such an influence since there is no global session object.

Tensorflow version: 1.0.1

Python 3.5.2

Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Why are you pickling the saver?

Comment: Sorry. That's an experiment, deleted now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a headache for the whole day.

just just solved:

the correct way is that you need to re-initialize all variables before calling restore()

for example, in the cifar10 project([cifar10.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10.py) - line 188)

if you wish to restores previously saved variables

you first need to call inference() for initialize all variables
and then call restore().

---

**re-initialize**

```
def restore(checkpoint_file=chk_file):
    with tf.Session() as session:
        x = tf.Variable(initial_value=[1, 2, 3], name="x")
        y = tf.Variable(initial_value=[[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0]], name="y")
        saver = tf.train.Saver()
        saver.restore(sess=session, save_path=checkpoint_file)
        print(session.run(tf.global_variables()[1]))
        print(tf.global_variables()[0])
        # print(session.run(tf.get_variable("x", shape=(3, ))))

def reset():
    tf.reset_default_graph()

restore("/home/kaiyin/PycharmProjects/text-classify/hello.chk")
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, but after reading your answer I still have no clue what is supposed to be done. Could you write up some code to clarify? Thanks!